# Hide PowerBI report in workspace

Tags: powerbi

I want to hide a dashboard. I know how to hide some information via RLS, but i dont know if is possible to hide the dashboard for al the people and the people that enter to the workspace can't see the dashboard, only the persona that upload it.

I tried RLS but i want to do it with another way.

Comment: Best to create an app, and give users access the that app rather than the workspace, as you can choose what items are included in the app.

Answer (score 0):

If possible, you can create a separate workspace with restricted access(only for you) and upload it there until you are ready to upload it to the global workspace.

Or

Play around with Workspace roles(don't give access(viewer, admin etc.) to anyone).